# How to run a multiline Powershell script inside of c#?

Tags: c#, powershell

I'd like to run this Powershell script inside of c# using the format below. Do I use -scriptblock or powershell.addscript("") or ? It seems like I'm making this harder than it should be.

Is there a preferred or standardized way to run larger precanned scripts inside of c#?

```
        PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create(RunspaceMode.NewRunspace);
        PSCommand command = new PSCommand();
        Collection<PSObject> psSessions = null;

        command.AddCommand("Get-PSSession");
        command.AddCommand("Remove-PSSession");

        powershell.Commands = command;
        psSessions = powershell.Invoke();

        command = new PSCommand();

        command.AddCommand("New-PSSession");
        command.AddParameter("AllowRedirection", true);
        command.AddParameter("Authentication", "Kerberos");
        command.AddParameter("ConfigurationName", "Microsoft.Exchange");
        command.AddParameter("ConnectionUri", pconnectionURI);
        command.AddParameter("Credential", Credential);

        powershell.Commands = command;
        psSessions = powershell.Invoke();
```

This is the multi line Powershell script below

```
try{
Get-Process -ProcessName Teams | Stop-Process -Force
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
Write-Host "Teams Process Sucessfully Stopped" -ForegroundColor Green
}catch{
echo $_
}
Write-Host "Clearing Teams Disk Cache" -ForegroundColor Yellow
try{
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:APPDATA\"Microsoft\teams\application cache\cache" | Remove-Item -Confirm:$false
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:APPDATA\"Microsoft\teams\blob_storage" | Remove-Item -Confirm:$false
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:APPDATA\"Microsoft\teams\databases" | Remove-Item -Confirm:$false
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:APPDATA\"Microsoft\teams\cache" | Remove-Item -Confirm:$false
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:APPDATA\"Microsoft\teams\gpucache" | Remove-Item -Confirm:$false
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:APPDATA\"Microsoft\teams\Indexeddb" | Remove-Item -Confirm:$false
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:APPDATA\"Microsoft\teams\Local Storage" | Remove-Item -Confirm:$false
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:APPDATA\"Microsoft\teams\tmp" | Remove-Item -Confirm:$false
Write-Host "Teams Disk Cache Cleaned" -ForegroundColor Green
}catch{
echo $_
}
Write-Host "Stopping Chrome Process" -ForegroundColor Yellow
try{
Get-Process -ProcessName Chrome| Stop-Process -Force
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
Write-Host "Chrome Process Sucessfully Stopped" -ForegroundColor Green
}catch{
echo $_
}
Write-Host "Clearing Chrome Cache" -ForegroundColor Yellow
try{
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:LOCALAPPDATA"\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache" | Remove-Item -Confirm:$false
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:LOCALAPPDATA"\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies" -File | Remove-Item -Confirm:$false
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:LOCALAPPDATA"\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Web Data" -File | Remove-Item -Confirm:$false
Write-Host "Chrome Cleaned" -ForegroundColor Green
}catch{
echo $_
}
Write-Host "Stopping IE Process" -ForegroundColor Yellow
try{
Get-Process -ProcessName MicrosoftEdge | Stop-Process -Force
Get-Process -ProcessName IExplore | Stop-Process -Force
Write-Host "Internet Explorer and Edge Processes Sucessfully Stopped" -ForegroundColor Green
}catch{
echo $_
}
Write-Host "Clearing IE Cache" -ForegroundColor Yellow
try{
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl, ClearMyTracksByProcess 8
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl, ClearMyTracksByProcess 2
Write-Host "IE and Edge Cleaned" -ForegroundColor Green
}catch{
echo $_
}
Write-Host "Cleanup Complete... Launching Teams" -ForegroundColor Green
Start-Process -FilePath $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\Teams\current\Teams.exe
Stop-Process -Id $PID
}else{
Stop-Process -Id $PID
}
```

Edit 1/27/21 9am

I'm able to get this to work, I will try and figure out how to pass the credentials externally rather than hard coding them and try a larger and more complicated script now as well.

```
string script = @"$computerName = 'xxxx';
$user = 'xxxx\xxxx'; 
$pw = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'xxxx' -AsPlainText -Force; 
$creds = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $pw; 
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName {get-childitem -path 'c:\'} -Credential $creds";
```

Edit 1/27/21 11am
The below works and will return the result of get-childitem with one issue, I'm getting an error message in addition to the folder results of. What's the fix for this error message?

> "The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command
> either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input
> and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take
> pipeline input."

```
// Credential is a c# object of System.Management.Automation.PSCredential
powershell.AddCommand("Set-Variable");
powershell.AddParameter("Name", "extCreds");
powershell.AddParameter("Value", Credential);
powershell.AddCommand("Set-Variable");
powershell.AddParameter("Name", "comp");
powershell.AddParameter("Value", "xxxx");

string script = @"$test1 = 'test1';
                            $test2 = 'test2';
                            $test3 = 'test3';
                            Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp {get-childitem -path 'c:\'} -Credential $extCreds"; 
powershell.AddScript(script);
            psSessions = powershell.Invoke();
```

Comment: [potentially useful documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/adding-and-invoking-commands?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: I would create a BAT file with the commands and test the bat files to make sure it runs in Windows.  Then just execute the bat from c#.